# Show the excerpt in a loop

Tags: excerpt

I want to display the 3 last post with this loop.

It works but I don't know why but the excerpt is always the same.

What did I do wrong?

```
 <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        ?>
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_left-to-right wpb_start_animation">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <p>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]) ?>">
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID']); ?>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]) ?>"><?php echo $recent["post_title"] ?></a></h3>
                        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"]); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: Is your recent ID definitely different each time?

Comment: Your code looks ok. Are you sure there is no plugin that tampers with the excerpt?

Comment: @Aravona Yes the id is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_the_excerpt function has issues using it with wp_get_recent_posts so instead of get_the_excerpt function use wp_trim_excerpt function in your code as displayed below.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    ?>
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_left-to-right wpb_start_animation">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]) ?>">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID']); ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]) ?>"><?php echo $recent["post_title"] ?></a></h3>
                    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( $recent['post_content'], 50, '...' ); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: @Vinond Dalvi Now I have different excerpt bur all the content of the post is displayed. The `wp_trim_excerpt()` function does not seem to work

Comment: You have to use the excerpt_length filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_length/ to control length of excerpt. The same applies to control get_the_excerpt length so it is not specific to wp_trim_excerpt

Comment: I have added a filter in my functions.php but nothing happened when I used `$recent['post_content']`... The filter works only with `the_excerpt()` but still, the same excerpt is displayed when I'm using that :(

Comment: I have changed the code a bit so could you please try using it?